# たら - a 'warning' or an 'if'?

Tags: meaning

> 時間がなかったので急いで食べていたら、舌を噛んでしまった。

Does this mean the person bit down and hurt his tongue? Or is it a warning not to eat fast?

Comment: You only need to look at the main clause, or its ending, to know he actually bit the tongue. `舌を噛んでしまった` means that regardless of what comes before it.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it's not a warning, though I suppose it could be taken that way though I doubt that's the intended meaning.  Also, it's not really an *if* in the sense that we would mean in English.

The speaker is saying, *Because there was no time, when I was quickly eating my food, I bit my tongue.*

As @aguijonazo
pointed out, the form of 噛んでしまった is a clue as to how to construe ~たら.  舌を噛んでしまった is definitely *I bit my tongue*.  Since this is thus a *fait accompli*, the clause ending in ~たら cannot be a conditional; it can only be spelling out the circumstances in which *I bit my tongue* occurred.

Comment: @fynxgloire, A.Ellett has the right of it.  The ～たら ending can mean "if", and it can also mean "when".  Depends on context.  In the context of your text, it cannot mean "if" and still make sense, so by process of elimination, we know that it must mean "when" instead.